# MongoDB C# Driver - update all fields in embedded array of documents

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this entity in DB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXX"),
    "Bets" : [ 
        {
            "IsPublic" : false
        }, 
        {
            "IsPublic" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to update all fileds *IsPublic* in nested documents. I have this query which works perfectly:

```
db.getCollection('bets').update({"_id": ObjectId("XXX")}, {$set : { "Bets.$[].IsPublic" : true }})
```

I want to write the same query with C# driver and I would prefer strongly typed query, something like this:

```
var filter = Builders<TrackerBet>.Filter.Eq(b => b.Id, "XXX");
var update = Builders<TrackerBet>.Update.Set(b => b.Bets[-1].IsPublic, true);
var result = mongoDb.Bets.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Result;
```

But it doesn't work. If I give up strongly typed query it works:

```
var update = Builders<TrackerBet>.Update.Set("Bets.$[].IsPublic", true);
```

Is it even possible to achieve a strongly-typed query? I thought that *b.Bets[-1].IsPublic* should do the trick, but I get the error *The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not aware of any built-in way to get this done using the official driver. i've written a [static utility class](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/MongoDB.Entities/Utilities/Prop.cs) that returns string paths for supplied lambda expressions. with it you can eliminate the hard-coded string like so:

```cs
    var path = Prop.PosAll<TrackerBet>(t => t.Bets[0].IsPublic);
    var update = Builders<TrackerBet>.Update.Set(path, true);
```

here's [more info](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/Extras#the-prop-class) on all the methods of the static class.